# Can I emulate a sticky key on the Mac platform?

Tags: macos, applescript, accessibility, appkit, foundation

With sticky keys enabled if you press `command` and then release it and then press `a` it's as if you had pressed `command-a`.

I'd like to make an AppleScript that holds `command` during one subsequent keystroke whatever that key may be.

I thought something simple would work. But I was wrong.

```
tell application "System Events"
key down command
key up command
end tell
```

### Update

I would be happy to receive answers using AppleScript or using the core appkit foundation stuff, or python, or anything.

The purpose is to make an assistive software for people who have a hard time typing. Rather than press modifier keys they can just say the name of the key and then hit the letter that goes with it.

Answer (score 0):

UI Scripting via System Events or any other framework does not have support for sticky keys.

(If you broaden your question to include what you're trying to accomplish, you may still be able to get more of a solution.)

Update:
For instance, if you need a function to make a modifier 'sticky', then can't you simply accomplish that with a flag? 
Something like:

```
property stickyCommand: false
on makeCommandSticky()
    set stickyCommand to true
end

on doKeyPress(k)
    if stickyCommand then
        tell app "System Events" to keystroke k using Command down
    else
        tell app "System Events" to keystroke k
    end if
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I have broadened my question.

Comment: Well, it wasn't just feedback, it was also an answer (even if it was the answer you were hoping for). Regarding your broader context, you can simulate modified key presses using core tech for sure, but you don't explain the context where you're needing a function to perform a sticky key. See suggestion in the answer text.